# Cant connect to google intermittently

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, google

Sometimes either randomly or after waking my late 2008 MacBook Pro from sleep, I won't be able to access google.com or any of the services. It's mildly annoying, but fixed by turning off my wifi, and then turning it back on.

When this happens, changing browsers doesn't help. I have a feeling this has to do with some sort of DNS issue, but I don't know why restarting my wifi would fix it. Has anyone else experienced this?

Late 2008 MacBook Pro
OSX Lion 10.7.4
Connected wirelessly to a 5th gen AEBS

any other information just ask, and I'm good with the Terminal

Comment: This happens to me, too - only google.com seems to be affected when my computer wakes up from sleep, and re-logging in to my user account on my laptop fixes the problem. Very odd.

Comment: What happens if you open the network assistant when you have problems? Are sites other than google affected or just that one domain?

Comment: It was just google.com for some reason. If it happens again I'll check the network assistant

Answer (score 1):

To isolate a DNS issue, you might try using google DNS by setting your Mac to use 8.8.8.8 instead of the DNS server it assigned or received from your router.

From there you can use `nslookup` and `ping` to test network connectivity and DNS resolution.

Comment: It hasn't happened for a while now in recent memory, but I do remember pinging google.com when it happened and it was timing out. I'm speculating it was something to do with the router, since disconnecting / reconnecting resolved the issue.